# Add reference to AppFabric dll for custom caching

Tags: 2013, caching, cache

I'm trying to add reference to the following dll so I can make use of AppFabric to cache some custom objects.

I've looked at this page
http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Improve-performance-of-your-SharePoint-2010-applications-using-Windows-Server-AppFabric-caching.aspx

and this ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790876.aspx

Which have been very helpful.  However, I cannot find

> C:\Windows\SysNative\AppFabric

when trying to add a reference from VS.  I can open the SysNative directory, but there is no AppFabric folder ... if I try to simply type the name, it says it does not exist.

I have though found the two dll's in

> 'C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server'

This is my first foray into AppFabric, so I don't know if these are the correct dll's to be using?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have the namespaces you need, go for it.

You've tagged it with '2013', are you using SharePoint 2013? Make sure that the AppFabric Cache cluster you're using is not the one SharePoint 2013 using, make sure it's on a server that's not one of your SharePoint servers and one that you're maintaining on your own. It's unsupported to use the AbbFabric Distributed Cache for your own applications.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219572.aspx

> If you are using custom applications in SharePoint Server 2013 which use the AppFabric client APIs, or are creating custom caches, you should create a separate AppFabric cache cluster to support your custom applications. Do not use the AppFabric cache cluster supporting your SharePoint Server 2013 farm. Run your separate AppFabric cache cluster for your custom applications on separate servers from the servers dedicated to your SharePoint Server 2013 farm.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I am using 2013 and after reading a few blogs on how to do it, I was planning to use the 2013 cluster.  It's rubbish that it's not supported.  Total crap from MS.  Having to create more servers etc for some simple caching.  Standard asp.net caching it is then!!  Thanks